# PopUp screen to select a person on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, fancybox

I have a "customer" class that stores all my customers.
And I have a "order" class in which I link a "customer" with his/her "products_list".

The thing is:
I want to select my customers from a popup form that shows me all my customers from database, so that, when clicking on his/her name, the popup closes and the name/id goes to my customer text_field.

I was taking a look at Fancybox but I don't think this "Click->Close->Send_Data" works...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't got loads of "customers", how about a `<select>` input?

If you have got loads of customers, how about an auto-completing text input?

Comment: I thought of the auto-completing text input but it will not work for my application.
I want to show a list of various customers all at once.
I also want to bring actions to create new customers or to edit one.

Comment: The question might be better suited to http://ux.stackexchange.com